# Cannot find -lcutil even though all the paths are correct

Tags: linker, cuda

When compiling some CUDA code, I get the error, that the `libcutil` cannot be found even though I checked that the paths are correct.

**Example**

```
$ nvcc mycudacode.cu -lcutil -o mycudaproject -I ~/NVIDIA_GPU_Computing_SDK/C/common/inc -L ~/NVIDIA_GPU_Computing_SDK/C/lib
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcutil
compilation terminated.
```

Even though:

```
$ ~/NVIDIA_GPU_Computing_SDK/C/lib$ ls
libcutil_x86_64.a  libparamgl_x86_64.a  librendercheckgl_x86_64.a
```

Comment: The error is a preprocessor error - `cutil.h` can't be found. Nothing to do with libraries. Check where that is located.

Comment: sorry for the confusion, I copied the wrong line from my shell, while compiling this question.

Comment: Again just read the error message. You are asking to link a library called `libcutil.a`. Do you see a library called `libcutil.a`?

Comment: You probably want to do: `nvcc mycudacode.cu -lcutil -o mycudaproject -I ~/NVIDIA_GPU_Computing_SDK/C/common/inc -L ~/NVIDIA_GPU_Computing_SDK/C/lib ~/NVIDIA_GPU_Computing_SDK/C/lib/libcutil_x86_64.a`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [NVIDIA Forums](http://forums.nvidia.com/index.php?showtopic=81929&pid=1042839&start=&st=#entry1042839):

On linux 64bit one has to rename `libcutil_x86_64.a` into `libcutil.a`.

So `cd` into the folder `$(HOME)/NVIDIA_GPU_Computing_SDK/C/lib/` (or where you installed CUDA) and enter: `cp libcutil_x86_64.a libcutil.a`

**DISCLAIMER**

As I already stumbled over this problem twice I added the question and the answer as a form of documentation.

Answer (score 3):

I have tried the following:

```
cp $(HOME)/NVIDIA_GPU_Computing_SDK/C/lib/libcutil_x86_64.a /usr/local/cuda/lib/libcutil.a
```

and it works.

Comment: What do you gain by copying the file into `/usr/local/`? +1 anyway