# CUDA linking error in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, cuda, makefile

I have been searching everywhere for a solution to my problem:
I cannot run a .cpp file using CUDA. I think this is a module error since I get the following error:

```
g++ -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 -L~/NVIDIA_GPU_Computing_SDK/shared/lib/linux -L~/NVIDIA_GPU_Computing_SDK/C/common/lib/linux -L~/NVIDIA_GPU_Computing_SDK/C/lib -lcutil -lcudpp -lcuda -lcudart -lcurand -o my_file my_file.o
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcutil
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcudpp
```

My makefile looks like this:

```
EXECUTABLE := my_file
SDKPATH := ~/NVIDIA_GPU_Computing_SDK
CUDAPATH := /usr/local/cuda

LDFLAGS := -L$(CUDAPATH)/lib64 -L$(SDKPATH)/shared/lib/linux -L$(SDKPATH)/C/common/lib/linux -L$(SDKPATH)/C/lib -lcutil -lcudpp -lcuda -lcudart -lcurand
CXFLAGS := -I$(CUDAPATH)/include -I$(SDKPATH)/shared/inc -I$(SDKPATH)/C/common/inc

CXX := g++
NVCC := $(CUDAPATH)/bin/nvcc

$(EXECUTABLE): my_file.o
    $(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) -o $(EXECUTABLE) my_file.o

my_file.o: my_file.cu
    $(NVCC) $(CXFLAGS) -c my_file.cu
```

When I, instead try to run the file manually I get the following output:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
my_file.o: In function `__cudaUnregisterBinaryUtil()':
tmpxft_00000e8f_00000000-1_my_file.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0xf): undefined reference to `__cudaUnregisterFatBinary'
my_file.o: In function `__sti____cudaRegisterAll_59_tmpxft_00000e8f_00000000_4_my_file_cpp1_ii_71dc03a4()':
tmpxft_00000e8f_00000000-1_my_file.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x1f): undefined reference to `__cudaRegisterFatBinary'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I'm a total noob when it comes to linux.
Can anyone please shed some light on this situation.

Regards

Answer (score 4):

You have an ordering problem in the linking phase of your build. Because the libraries you specify are provided *before* the files that require them, they get discarded. If you change your makefile to something like:

```
LDFLAGS := -L$(CUDAPATH)/lib64 -L$(SDKPATH)/shared/lib/linux -L$(SDKPATH)/C/common/lib/linux
LIBS := -lcutil -lcudpp -lcuda -lcudart -lcurand

....

$(EXECUTABLE): my_file.o
    $(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) -o $(EXECUTABLE) my_file.o $(LIBS)
```

you should find the problem goes away.

Comment: I still get the following error:
g++ -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 -L~/NVIDIA_GPU_Computing_SDK/shared/lib/linux -L~/NVIDIA_GPU_Computing_SDK/C/common/lib/linux -o my_file my_file.o -lcutil -lcudpp -lcuda -lcudart -lcurand
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcutil
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcudpp
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [my_file] Error 1

Any thoughts on how to fix it?

Comment: I think that problem has been addressed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7770850/cannot-find-lcutil-even-though-all-the-paths-are-correct).

Comment: Well, I tried it and, I am sorry to say, I still get the exact same error.

Comment: So the linker can't find libcutil and libcudpp.  Let's separate those two issues.  First let's tackle libcutil.  Where is it?    Have you built the SDK samples?    If so, you'll need to locate where libcutil is in that directory structure.  I am looking at a CUDA 4.1 setup and libcutil_x86_64.a is in <SDKPATH>/C/lib, and that's **not** one of the directories you're telling the linker to look in (with the -L switches).  So fix that first, and see if we can make that error go away.  As already indicated, you may need to rename the libcutil file for ubuntu.

Comment: I should point out that the <SDKPATH>/C/lib *is* in your makefile in the original post but not in the command line you are giving in this comments section.  For libcudpp, [have you installed cudpp](http://code.google.com/p/cudpp/)?

Comment: @FrankenFeynman: Note you are now getting a different error than in your original question, which was effectively because the CUDA runtime library (libcudart.so) wasn't being linked.